# If R is an equivalence relation, and S is only symmetric and transitive, what is R ∪ S?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, relations, equivalence-relations

I have a question that asks the following:

> Let R and S be binary relations on a set A. Suppose that R is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive and that S is symmetric, and transitive but is not reflexive. Which statement is always true for any choice of R and S with the above properties? Only one of the following choices is correct. Provide a proof for your choice.
>
> (a) R ∪ S is symmetric but not reflexive and not transitive.
>
> (b) R ∪ S is symmetric but not reflexive.
>
> (c) R ∪ S is transitive and symmetric but not reflexive.
>
> (d) R ∪ S is reflexive and symmetric, but not transitive.

I think that the correct answer is d) because if R is reflexive, then for every x ∈ A, we have that (x,x) ∈ R. If (x,x) ∈ R, then (x,x) must also be in R ∪ S. So R ∪ S should be reflexive. However, I feel like I can apply that logic to the symmetric and transitive argument. So why would R ∪ S be symmetric but not transitive also? Is my choice wrong? Would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instincts are right: (d) is the correct answer, and the proof that $R \cup S$ is symmetric is similar to the proof for reflexivity. You should have a go at it.

The reason that transitivity (might) fail is that transitivity takes two inputs, so it is entirely possible that one input is in $R$ but not $S$ and the other is in $S$ but not $R$. That way, you can't get anything from the transitivity of $R$ or $S$.

You should finish the proof by finding a small example of a pair of relations $R$ and $S$ on a set which satisfy the conditions but whose union isn't transitive.

Answer (score 1):

Your choice is correct.  $T=R\cup S$ is not necessarily transitive.  Suppose $xTy$ and $xTz.$  It could be that $xRy$ and $ySz$ and we cannot conclude either than $yRz$ or $xSy$ so there is no way to conclude that $xTz.$

With this hint, I'm sure you won't have trouble finding a counterexample.